# Is the following statement true or false and also what about when union of sets is taken?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S_1$ and $S_2$ be subsets of a vector space $V(F)$ then

$$ \operatorname{span}(S_1 \cap S_2) = \operatorname{span}(S_1) \cap \operatorname{span}(S_2)$$

Comment: It's super-false.

Answer (score 2):

Counterexample in $\Bbb R^2$: $S_1=\{\hat{i},\,\hat{j}\},\,S_2=\{\hat{i}+\hat{j},\,\hat{i}-\hat{j}\}$. If we replace $\cap$ with $\cup$ throughout, we can still find a counterexample: $S_1=\{\hat{i}\},\,S_2=\{\hat{j}\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

It is quite well possible that $S_1\cap S_2=\varnothing$ while $\mathsf{span}(S_1)=\mathsf{span}(S_2)$.